# What are the pros and cons of joining the Quadrilateral Security Dialogue Plus group instead of joining the main Quadrilateral Security Dialogue?

Tags: international, geopolitics, south-korea

What are the pros and cons of joining the Quadrilateral Security Dialogue Plus group instead of joining the main Quadrilateral Security Dialogue? I was wondering why a country like South Korea would choose to join the Quadrilateral Security Dialogue Plus group, but not the main Quadrilateral Security Dialogue Plus group.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadrilateral_Security_Dialogue#Quad_Plus_Meetings

> In March 2020, the Quad members held a meeting with representatives
> from New Zealand, South Korea and Vietnam to discuss their respective
> approaches to the ongoing COVID-19 pandemic.[15] **The participation of
> representatives from New Zealand, South Korea and Vietnam, the latter
> being the first country from Southeast Asia/ASEAN to join, was seen as
> another attempt to expand the importance of the QUAD as well as the
> growing threat China posed in the region.[91] Instigated by the US,
> this new grouping of key Indo-Pacific states was referred to as "Quad
> Plus".** A further meeting was held in May 2021 where Brazil and Israel,
> two countries with no border to the Pacific Ocean, were invited into
> the Plus format to discuss the distribution of COVID-19 vaccines.[91]

The Wikipedia article on the group doesn't really explain what the differences are and if there are duties and benefits that come with joining the full group as opposed to joining the plus group.

It feels as though the plus group serves a completely different purpose even if there's a claim of it stating otherwise.